# How to check python is installed on the node or not in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to check whether python is installed on the node or agent. I have used declarative pipeline script to check below is my i have tried. i struck in this

```
pipeline {
 agent none
 stages {
    stage('Test On Windows') {
     agent {
      label "windows"
     }
     steps {
        echo "GIT_CLONE_STARTED"
        git "${GIT_REPO_URL}/${GIT_REPO_NAME}.git"
        echo "GIT_CLONE_ENDED"
      echo "running on windows"
      python init.py
     }
    }
    stage('Executing python scripts') {
      agent {
      label "windows"
     }
     steps {
       python init.py
     }
    }
 }
}
```

And also need to check for both windows and linux machines.

Comment: Error would help us to have a look at what exactly is the issue you are facing. To start with you are using windows slave but shell $ for echo?

Comment: I don't know where to check python is installed on node. No idea in that. i have both windows and linux slave machine to check python is installed on that machine or not to execute python files

Comment: Python --version would be best way to check if python is installed or not. Sh '''python --version'''. Bat '''python --version''' '''

Comment: i dont know how to check with if condition